# Navigate from an area to a page with no area in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-routing

I set up my routing to load `/AreaName/Home/Index`by default and when adding this

`<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Application" asp-action="Index"</a>`,

to `Index.cshtml` I would expect it to go to `/Application/Index`, but when hovering over the link the url looks like this `localhost:######/AreaName/Application/` instead of `localhost:######/Application/`.

I think my routing is a bit off. Here's what I tried:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        template: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { area = "AreaName", controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "SomeName",
        template: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { area = string.Empty, controller = "Application", action = "Index" }    
    );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This seems to be working now with asp.net core 3.1

Answer (score -2):

Your routing table should have a default route without an area, your current configuration will always lead to a route with area name = AreaName because you defaulted it to "AreaName" in your first route.

Copy the first route and remove the area section from it and remove the second one.

Comment: The reason I set a default area is because I want that area to be loaded when the app starts. But in doing that, now I can't navigate out of the area

Comment: Why do you set the default page to be inside an area? 
If it is a must, just add a redirect inside the default Home controller on the root to the other controller inside the area